# JSeparator with Title

Tags: java, swing

How do I create a horizontal JSeparator with a title label in Java Swing?

Something like this:

```
--- Title XYZ --------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution: [SwingX JXTitledSeparator](http://javadesktop.org/swinglabs/build/weekly/latest/swingx-HEAD/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTitledSeparator.html). We already use SwingX in our project. I didn't know that SwingX provides a titled separator.

**@Bombe** Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm… without any testing and completely from the top of my head:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Title"));
menu.add(panel);
```

Most Swing containers eat anything so that might even work.

Another approach would be to create a custom component (maybe with a horizontal BoxLayout) and add a JSeparator, a JLabel, and another JSeparator to it, then add it to the menu.